# C++, sprintf with hex parameter

Tags: c++, c

I try to understand following code:

```
char temp[50];
sprintf(temp,"%04XT1000A",Edit3->Text.ToInt());
```

I know that T1000A is a simple string and I know the meaning of it, but what is %04X? Is %04X completely replaced by the parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`%04` is a format specifier modifier saying that if the output is less than 4 chars it should be padded on the left with `0`. `%X` is standard format specifier meaning print unsigned  hexadecimal use capital letters for A-F. Have a look at [printf's](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) documentation.

Comment: @artworkadシ btw this is more `c` than `c++` specific. Maybe you should add the tag?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: What makes you think it isn't C++?  The `printf` family of functions is clearly defined in the C++ specification.  There are cases where using `snprintf` to a buffer is simpler to use than `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know and that is why I believe question should be tagged with both tags.  The idea being that it should be discoverable to people using c too.